# How can I create an object and pass it to a property in XAML markup?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I have a custom UserControl that I am trying to use in my XAML windows app. I have a property that is a ref class. I want to create the object and assign it to the property via markup alone. Is this possible?

None of the following syntax is compiling:

```
<MyCustomControl
    Helper="ref new local:HelperClass()"/>

<MyCustomControl
    Helper="{x:Bind local:HelperClass()}"/>
```

Note: I want to avoid needing to create properties/instantiate in code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<MyCustomControl>
    <MyCustomControl.Helper>
        <local:HelperClass />
    </MyCustomControl.Helper>
</MyCustomControl>
```